# How to get rid of WARNING: Using -cpinternal UTF-8 is not supported for TTY clients. You may corrupt files or databases. (11994)

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

Interactive _progres on tty with -cpinternal utf-8 nags the user with

```
WARNING: Using -cpinternal UTF-8 is not supported for TTY clients. You may corrupt files or databases. (11994)
Press space bar to continue.
```

Our database are all utf-8, and have been so for at least a decade.

I've seen lots of db corruption caused by using non utf-8 cpinternal on a utf-8 database. I have never experienced any issues by the limited use of interactive tty -cpinternal utf-8 sessions we use.

This warning is really annoying because it

- make users believe some intentional config is wrong
- requires the users to press space bar to continue.

Is there a way to get rid of this warning or to automatically press the space bar ?

Comment: Replace ``DO NOT CONTINUE`` in promsgs with ``Space Continues``? :-)

Comment: see also https://openedge.ideas.aha.io/ideas/OPENEDGE-I-1565

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `-noutf8warning` parameter to get rid of the message.

Tested in OpenEdge 12.2. I don't know when it was introduced

Comment: It was introduced twenty three years ago in 9.1C :-) http://www.oehive.org/node/1491.html but has no effect on Windows (tested 11.7.17 and 12.2.12)